# iOS-Chart : Increasing bar width in grouped sets of BarChartView

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm trying to increase the bar width in chartBarView .
there is my code :

```
let groupSpace = 0.01
let barSpace = 0.01
let barWidth = 0.32
// (0.32 + 0.01) * 3 + 0.01 = 1.00

let groupCount = 9
let startMonth = 0


chartData.barWidth = barWidth;
barChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = Double(startMonth)
let spaceIndividualBar = chartData.groupWidth(groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
print("spaceIndividualBar must be equan to 1 : \(spaceIndividualBar)")
barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(startMonth) + spaceIndividualBar * Double(groupCount)

chartData.groupBars(fromX: Double(startMonth), groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
```

I want to double the width of the individual bars than this result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the space between two bar its increase the bar Width.

Comment: Thanks, theoricaly it can be down like what you tell, but in fact my question is about iOS-Chart library who has particular behavior when modifying certains properties related to sizes